# Escaping space in the URI

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create a linked folder programmatically in Eclipse and link the zip file which is at a location outside the workspace using Eclipse EFS.

I am getting the following exception

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 20: zip:/?file:///D:/New Folder/documentation.zip
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2810)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2983)
```

the problem is the space in the URI.

I tried replacing the space with `%20` and "`+`", but neither one worked.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This question will end up collecting a large number of negative votes.please accept some of the answers to avoid that and to encourage others to answer

Comment: Replacing the space with %20 eliminates the URISyntaxException. Are you sure you're getting the same error once you've done that?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 14: file:///D:/New Folder/documentation.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double escape it with `%2520` and it will work.